# Set multiple background images for navigation link dividers

Tags: css, navigationbar, divider

I am trying to set a divider image between links in the navigation bar. I currently have it set up as a background image, positioned to the right. This works fine, except I also want the divider to appear to the left of the first link. I have tried adding `background-position:right,left;` to the first link class, but this doesn't work. Any ideas on how I would do this?

Comment: HTML / CSS in a JSfiddle please...including actual image.

Comment: Essentially, what I have is this: http://jsfiddle.net/P25TC - I just need the background image to appear on the left hand side of the first link too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to support old school browsers, the easiest way is probably with multiple background images like this: http://jsfiddle.net/P25TC/1/

```
#nav li.first{
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/CED9fuN.png) no-repeat left, url(http://i.imgur.com/CED9fuN.png) no-repeat right;
}
```